# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »um« und »um ... herum«

Tags: grammar, difference, preposition

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen folgenden Sätzen:

> Der Hund geht um den Tisch.
>
> Sie gehen um den Turm herum.

Warum benutzt man *um* in einem Satz und *um ... herum* im anderen? Ist die Idee nicht gleich?

Comment: It's  "herumgehen" in the second sentence (not "um... herum").

Comment: Thanks for clearing the verb. But can you explain what would be the difference between the sentences, "Sie gehen um den Turm" and "Sie gehen um den Turm herum"?

Comment: Nicht so clever, einmal einen Hund auftreten zu lassen, einmal sie; einmal einen Tisch, einmal einen Turm. Den Unterschied zw. um und um...herum sieht man ja eher, wenn alles andere gleich bleibt, als wenn man alles andere gleich mit ändert.

Answer (score 2):

Deine Beispiele sind nicht ideal gewählt, denn man könnte das zweite so auffassen, dass es das trennbare Verb *herumgehen* enthält. Dennoch lassen sich zwei verwandte Beispiele finden:

> Um den Tisch sind Stühle.
>
> Um den Tisch herum sind Stühle.

Das erste beschreibt nur, dass die Stühle auf einer Ebene stehen, und keiner davon im Tisch. Das zweite fügt zusätzlich die Information hinzu, dass die Stühle ansatzweise geordnet um den Tisch herumstehen; also ungefähr einen Kreis bilden.

Das lässt sich auch (etwas loser) auf Beispiele mit *gehen* versus *herumgehen* übertragen: Der Hund geht *um den Tisch*, weil er nicht hindurch kann (er ist zu groß). Er geht aber an einen Ort, der von seinem Startpunkt aus gesehen *hinter* dem Tisch ist. Deswegen muss er um den Tisch einen Bogen schlagen. Wenn sie allerdings um den Tisch *herumgehen,* dann kreisen sie um den Tisch, sie entfernen sich nicht von ihm.

Das heißt, die beiden Begriffe beschreiben Ähnliches, aber nicht Identisches.

Comment: Nja, _herumgehen_ wird auch für das Ausweichen benutzt, nicht nur für das Umkreisen: _Du gehst um das Gebäude herum zum Hintereingang._ (180°)

Comment: @chirlu Aber wenn ich den Hintereingang suche, ist es wieder eine Sorte Umkreisen.

Comment: "Das erste beschreibt nur, dass die Stühle auf einer Ebene stehen, und keiner davon im Tisch". Neither **in** the table, nor **on** or **under** it, right? Would "um" be used instead of "neben" if all chairs were on a single side of the table? Could you give me an example of chairs positions around the table which would not roughly comprise a circle and in which "um" would be used?

Answer (score 0):

Die Floskel »um etwas gehen« ist mehrdeutig:

> 1. Ich bin gleich wieder da, ich *gehe* nur schnell *um eine Schachtel Zigaretten* zur Trafik hinunter.
> 2. Lassy *ging* über den Teppich, *um die Bodenvase*, dann hinaus in den Vorraum, wo sie verdutzt stehen blieb, weil ihr Fressnapf weg war.

1 ist eigentlich eine Verkürzung von »gehen, um etwas zu holen«. Jemand geht also irgendwo hin, und hat dabei die Absicht, das Akkusativobjekt am Ziel an sich zu nehmen, um es zum Ausgangspunkt zu transportieren.
Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob diese Formulierung im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum Verwendung findet. Hinweise zur geographischen Verteilung wird man sicherlich in den Kommentaren nachlesen können. Jedenfalls ist diese Phrase Teil der österreichischen Umgangssprache, ich messe ihr aber keinen hohen stilistischen Wert bei.

In der Bedeutung von 2 kann man die Phrase tatsächlich in jedem Fall um das Wort »herum« ergänzen, wobei sich die Bedeutung in den meisten Fällen inhaltlich gar nicht, und wenn doch, dann nur geringfügig verändert. Eine Ergänzung um das Wort »herum« stellt in vielen Fällen aber eine stilistische Verbesserung dar, ohne grammatisch zwingend notwendig zu sein.

In beiden Fällen kann das Verb (bisher war es immer »*gehen*«) durch ein beliebiges anderes Bewegungsverb ersetzt werden, sofern das semantisch sinnvoll ist.

> 1. - Schon seit vier Stunden ist mein Mann weg. Dabei hat er gesagt, dass er nur *um eine Kiste Bier fährt*.
>    - Geh, Jürgen, da hast' fünf Euro, *lauf'* mir bitte *um eine Jause*.
> 2. - Der Bolide *kurvt um das Hindernis (herum)*, verliert dabei aber wertvolle Hundertstel.
>    - Irene *segelt um das Riff (herum)*.

Im Fall 2 kann man das Verb auch durch eines jener Verben ersetzen, die ausdrücken, das sich etwas irgendwo befindet. Es wird also anstelle einer Bewegung eine örtliche Lage zum Ausdruck gebracht:

> Die Scherben *liegen* rund *um den Esstisch (herum)*.
>   *Um den Eingang (herum) stehen* teure Autos.

Beide Sätze sagen aus, dass sich mehrere Elemente in der Nähe eines zentralen Objekts befinden, ohne eine Bewegung zu vollführen. Diese Elemente nehmen (in loser Streuung oder auch wohl geordnet) den verfügbaren Platz in der Nähe dieses Objekts ein.

Auch Verben die das Ende einer zielgerichteten Bewegung bedeuten sind möglich:

> Die Jünger *versammelten* sich *um den Tisch*.
>   Die Autogrammjäger *scharten* sich *um den Bühnenausgang*.

Die letzten beiden Beispiele sagen nicht aus, das eine Bewegung eine Bahn hat, die an einem Objekt vorbei, und danach von ihm weg führt, sondern dass sie in der Nähe des Zeil-Objekts endet. Diese Bewegung wird von mehren voneinander unabhängigen Elementen vollführt, und zwar so, dass deren Endpositionen dem entsprechen, was zuvor für *liegen*, *stehen* usw. beschrieben wurde.

Das Hinzufügen von »*herum*« zwar auch hier möglich, führt aber im Gegensatz zu den zuvor behandelten Beispielen zu einem stilistisch weniger gutem Ergebnis:

> Die Jünger versammelten sich um den Tisch *herum*.
>   Die Autogrammjäger scharten sich um den Bühnenausgang *herum*.

Comment: Meines Wissens geht man nur in Österreich um eine Zeitung. Sonst überall 'um zu kaufen', 'zu klauen', 'zu besorgen', 'zu kriegen' usw. Dass das nicht gemeint war in der Frage geht aus dem Allgemeinwissen über Hunde und Tische hervor.

Comment: Ich stimme der Einschätzung, dass *um eine Schachtel* Österreichisch ist. Bei uns in Bayern wäre es *für eine Schachtel,* wenn ich das richtig bewerte. (Aber ich gehe höchstens für ein Guzzl.)

Comment: Ich denke nicht, daß die österreichische Verwendung ein verkürztes _um … zu_ ist, sondern es dürfte die übliche Präposition sein. Auch _um_ für Preisangaben (_um 3 Euro verkaufen_) ist nicht gemeindeutsch, allerdings auch nicht auf Österreich beschränkt.